# Is it possible to take a soldering iron aboard an airplane?

Tags: air-travel, legal, electronic-items, hand-luggage

I need to know may I transfer soldering iron using airplane?
Is it prohibited item?

What if the soldering iron works using 4V batteries?
If inside soldering iron there is no battery then why it might be prohibited items?
It can not be heated.
The temperature of it can not be increased.

For example answer me about [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001O9P75Y) one?

What about 120-220volt soldering iron?

Comment: You can run a soldering iron of a 4v battery?

What airline(s)/country(ies) are you planning on flying with/from/to (probably doesn't matter, but always useful to know.

Comment: I am transferring from USA to Georgia

Comment: The fact it can be heated wouldn't be the part that would (potentially - I don't know if it is or it isn't) make it a prohibited item. I imagine you could do some pretty serious damage stabbing somebody with the one you linked, since it's made of metal and tapers to a (dull) point. If it was just the tip it might be allowed (comment, not an answer, so don't take this as a statement of fact), but attach it to a handle and you have yourself a weapon.

Comment: I don't see why this is an issue, just pack it in your check-in luggage, remove the batteries ?? Or there is an embargo on trade tools like that?

Comment: @Max If you're not travelling with much else then avoiding checking in luggage at all is generally a positive. If you absolutely have to transport this item, and it's prohibited from carry-on, then yeah, you'll have to check a bag. However, it's worth finding out if it actually *is* prohibited first.

Comment: [Delta's rule](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/before-your-trip/restricted-items.html):  **Heat-Producing Items — We allow battery-operated underwater torches (diving lamps) and soldering irons, 7 inches (18 cm) or less in length, as carry-on baggage only.** That's a pretty short soldering iron (178mm). I guess you could plug a mains powered soldering iron into the seat power source.

Comment: 4V or 220V, seems you just want to take *SOME* soldering iron onboard, sounds fishy!

Answer (score 3):

The consensus on the internet is mixed, with [people who managed to carry their soldering iron in hand luggage without any problems](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=13243&p=139524), as well as [others who had it confiscated and thrown away by TSA](https://thetsablog.wordpress.com/category/share-your-tsa-experiences/). However, the TSA prohibited items search engine does not provide any indication on the topic. The only US-related official source I could find is **[the Delta Airlines webpage on Baggage Restrictions](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/before-your-trip/restricted-items.html), which states that soldering irons 18cm or less can be taken aboard a flight as carry-on luggage only**:

> #### Other Possible Hazardous Items
>
> [...]
>
> **Heat-Producing Items** — We allow battery-operated underwater torches (diving lamps) and soldering irons, 7 inches (18 cm) or less in length, as carry-on baggage only.

The best piece of advice I can give you is: put it in your checked-in luggage to avoid any hassle. Personally I wouldn't want to gamble with TSA, especially if this is some tool that is either expensive or fundamental to you when you land in Georgia. Otherwise, if you insist on having the soldering iron with you on board, contact your airline and ask them.